# How to equate the amplitude of two sinusoidal signals in gnu radio?

Tags: python, gnuradio, amplitude

I have two sinusoidal signals with different amplitude. I would like to equate the amplitude of the two signals. For instance, if the amplitude of the second signal is lower than the first signal's one, I want to equate both.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see [ask]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "equating", either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could normalize them:

```
A1 = B*sin(...);
A2 = C*sin(...)

A3 = A1/max(A1);
A4 = A2/max(A2)
```

Then you'll get to signals with amplitude 1